# When is there a 1-1 correspondence between relative discs and those in a cover?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space with covering $p : \tilde{X} \to X$ and $A \subset X$. Consider the set of maps $M := \{u: (D^n, \partial D^n) \to (X,A)\}$ taking $n$-dimensional discs to $X$ with boundaries lying in $A$. Let $\tilde{A} \subset \tilde{X}$ be the "induced cover" of $A$ such that $p(\tilde{A}) = A$. What conditions ensure the set of maps $\tilde{M} :=\{\tilde{u}: (D^n, \partial D^n) \to (\tilde{X},\tilde{A})\}$ is in bijection with $M$?  (I am particularly interested in the case $n=2$). More generally, how do we relate the two sets?

For example: take $X = \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \times S^1 \times S^1$ and $A = \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}\times S^1 \times \{0\}$ so that  $\tilde{X} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}  \times \mathbb{R} $ and $\tilde{A}= \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}\times \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$. How does $\{u : D^2 \to X | \partial u \in  A\}$ relate to $\{\tilde{u} : D^2 \to \tilde{X} | \partial \tilde{u} \in  \tilde{A} \}$?

Comment: As long as $|X|=|\tilde{X}|= \mathfrak c=|\Bbb R|$ and by maps you mean continuous maps and $M$ and $\tilde{M}$ are non-empty, we have $|M|=|\tilde{M}|=\mathfrak c=|\Bbb R|$. If the question is about maps up to homotopy (or something else), you should specify this. I still doubt anyone will give you a useful answer to your question. In a lot of ways this question is answered by any basic book on algebraic topology.

Comment: I suppose he implicitly wants the bijection to be induced by postcomposing with $p$, i.e. the question is about existence and uniqueness of lifts of maps of pairs.

Comment: @archipelago. That's exactly right, I didn't know the best way to formulate the question. As far as I can tell there is no obvious tool in Hatcher that can be used to answer this question unless there is some extended Corollary I am missing?

Comment: If you start with a map of pairs $(D^n,\partial D^n)\rightarrow (X,A)$, you can lift it considered as a map $D^n\rightarrow X$. The result will be a map of pairs $(D^n,\partial D^n)\rightarrow (\tilde{X},p^{-1}(A))$, so basically there is no difference in lifting maps of pairs in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p: \tilde X \to X$ be a covering map. Let $f: D^n \to X$. Note $D^n \cong D^{n-1}\times I$ so $f$ can be thought of as homotopy between two maps $f_0,f_1:D^{n-1} \to X$. Moreover one can arrange the homeomorphism $h$ between $D^{n-1}\times I$ and $D^n$ so that $h(D^{n-1}\times 0)$ is contained in any given open set $U\subset D^n$ containing a point of $\partial D^n$. In particular, one can arrange $h$ so that there exists an open $V\subset X$ with $f (h(D^{n-1}\times 0))\subset V$ with $p|_{p^{-1}(V)}:p^{-1}(V)\to V$ being the trivial cover with the same number of sheets as the original cover of $X$.

Now, the lifts of $f_0=f|_{h(D^{n-1}\times 0)}:D^{n-1}\to X$ correspond exactly to the sheets of the cover. By the homotopy lifting property (proposition 1.30 Hatcher), there exists a unique lift of the homotopy $f$ between $f_0$ and $f_1$ for each lift of $f_0$. We have arranged so the lifts of $f_0$ correspond exactly to the sheets of the cover. So the push-forward map $p_*:C(D^n,\tilde X) \to C(D^n, X)$ is $n$ to $1$, where $n$ is the number of sheets of the cover $p$. It is trivial to see that $p_*$ restricts to an $n$ to $1$ map from maps $(D^{n-1},\partial D^n) \to  (\tilde X, p^{-1}(A))$ to maps $(D^{n-1},\partial D^n) \to (X,A)$ (this is basically archipelago's second comment). In particular the only times when $p_*$ is a bijection are when the cover is $1$-sheeted or $M = \emptyset$.